# Can I override to_param in model from activeadmin form submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have inherited a system that was created using Active Admin.  I needed to add one of the models, "report", into Active Admin.  I did this, checked the index displays in the dashboard and all looked well.  However, when I tried to use any of the CRUD functionality it breaks returning the error:

```
Couldn't find Report with id=name_of_report
```

The problem is Active Admin is producing routes like this (where report_title is the report.title value):

http://localhost:3000/admin/reports/report_title

instead of:

http://localhost:3000/admin/reports/1

A look at the model shows that the problem is related to the report model having a to_param method:

```
def to_param
  title
end
```

If I remove this then my active admin pages start to work fine.  However, a large amount of report functionality has been written which breaks if I remove the to_param because it needs the URL to be in format detailed above (http://localhost:3000/admin/reports/).

I've managed to create my own links using "link_to" for add, view, delete (see below).  I also have the new link working in a similar way.

***app/admin/reports.rb***

```
index do
  selectable_column
  column :title
  column :id
  column :column_method
  column :row_method

  actions defaults: false do |action|
    link_to("View",   admin_report_path(action.id),      { :class=> "member_link view_link" } ) + 
    link_to("Edit",   edit_admin_report_path(action.id), { :class=> "member_link view_link" } ) + 
    link_to("Delete", admin_report_path(action.id),      { :class=> "member_link view_link" },  method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' })
  end
end
```

The problem is I can't get the form to update or create the details from the form when it's submitted.

I was wondering if anyone else has experienced this problem and knew of way of getting around it?

Many thanks in advance for any suggestions.

**EDIT**

Timo's solution worked fine for me, many thanks for such a speedy response.  For those interested my report.rb program now looks like this:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Report do

  controller do
    resources_configuration[:self][:finder] = :find_by_title
  end

  index do
    selectable_column
    column :title
    column :id
    column :column_method
    column :row_method

    actions

  end

  form do |f|
    f.inputs 'Details' do
      f.input :title
      f.input :column_method
      f.input :row_method
      f.input :id     # This should probably be hidden.....

      f.buttons
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: You need to pass `title` instead of `id` in the ***links***. Eg:- `admin_report_path(action.title)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ActiveAdmin.register Report do
  controller do
    resources_configuration[:self][:finder] = :find_by_title
  end
end
```

Source / Docs: https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources/blob/1ca42fedd8831f083490089dbf4609bc7e354fff/lib/inherited_resources/base_helpers.rb#L219